# Xamarin.Forms shared preferences how to save object to list

Tags: xamarin.forms, local-storage, sharedpreferences

i'm using xamarin.forms , and have a scenario like this:
When user submit a form i get a object. I need to save that object in list and every time user add new submit  i need to save the object in the same list. I know how to save a object and Array of objects but don't know how do add object in list in shared preferences . I need a code for this in Android and also in IOS. For every user locale need to have one list in which i can save and also delete objects user submit. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use SQLite in that case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Comment: @FreakyAli thank u i totally forgot about sqlLite. Just one question. SQLite is locallly create for every user. If u delete cache everything delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just one question. SQLite is locallly create for every user. If u delete cache everything delete?

Do you want to clear the cache or clear the Storage like following screenshot?
[image]

If you clear the cache, the sqlite DB will not be delete.

If you clear the storage, your local Sqlite DB will be delete, you will get following Alert.

[image]

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Answer (score 1):

Use Newtonsoft Json and serialize object first and then store as string in Xamarin essentials preference api and deserialize when you need it back.